# Is it safe to use $_SESSION to save your root path for INCLUDES?

Tags: php

Is it safe, in my login form, or after logging in, to use `$_SESSION['path']` to store the absolute path to my root folder, then call the folder elsewhere in my project? Using: `include_once($_SESSION['path'] . "folder/file.php")`.

Comment: It should be resaonably safe since your file is on the server side and as long as you dont allow variables in the file path leading to the file however you should be very careful whne editing the file to not introduce any errors (personally ID refer you to using a database this way at least the structural integrity is kept )

Comment: for a small server for a limited amount of people I dont think thers a problem but for a production system I dont think its optimal

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  When you say, Use a Database, do you mean store the absolute path in my database, call it in my project and save it to the session variable?

Comment: oh sorry I tohught you were storing user variables in a file but its just the filename yeah i dont see any problems with that if it works syntactically just again make sure to under no circumstances allow the user to change it

Comment: Yeah, it's just to store the absolute path so I can use it on several pages when I include files.  No user input.

Comment: by the way this variable sound like it could also be provided by the server

Comment: i foudn this : `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I havent double checked what it prints

Answer (score 0):

If the session path is not user-specific, and you know how to work out the value, then why not apply the same method elsewhere? OTOH if you are using this as a method for providing different behaviours to different users, then I would strongly recommend that you rethink your strategy - this does not scale well and will not lead to a well engineered solution. Potentially it could lead to LFI vulnerabilities in your code (but only in the presence of other defects) or TOCTOU type exploits.

Generally data stored in the session can be considered safe as long as you take the usual precautions to prevent against session fixation and session hijacking attacks, you trust all the code running on the server and there are no other other vulnerabilities in the system. Its probably not the right way to solve the problem though.